# Better Way to create XML for inherit xml node from excel

Tags: python, xml, excel, vba, xlrd

I have a xml document and i have xsd file for this . Now i want to generate the xml file based on the excel input. Issue i am facing when xml document has multiple element nodes. I am not getting idea how to handle this part as excel Import xml is not handle this type of structure.

Is VBA will help here ? Any hint/idea will helpfull.

XML Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Sample>
<Sample-List>
<Id>3342</Id>
<Version>3342</Version>
<Name>TypeC</Name>
<Vendor>
    <Vendor-Id>xxx</Vendor-Id>
    <Vendor-Name>SAM</Vendor-Name>
    <Vendor-Type>
        <Vendor-Type-Id>AAAA-1</Vendor-Type-Id>
        <Vendor-Type-Code>AAAA-2</Vendor-Type-Code>
        <Vendor-Type-Mode>Active</Vendor-Type-Mode>
        <Vendor-Type-AC-Min>1</Vendor-Type-AC-Min>
        <Vendor-Type-AC-Max>4</Vendor-Type-AC-Max>
        <Vendor-Type-depends-on>
            <EMP-Code>AAAA-3</EMP-Code>
            <EMP-Id>AAAA-4</EMP-Id>
            <EMP-Name>AAAA-5</EMP-Name>
            <EMP-Details>
                <Property-Code>AAAA-6</Property-Code>
                <Cash-Code>AAAA-7</Cash-Code>
            </EMP-Details>
            <EMP-Details>
                <Property-Code>AAAA-8</Property-Code>
                <Cash-Code>AAAA-9</Cash-Code>
            </EMP-Details>
        </Vendor-Type-depends-on>
    </Vendor-Type>
    <Vendor-Type>
        <Vendor-Type-Id>BBBB-1</Vendor-Type-Id>
        <Vendor-Type-Code>BBBB-2</Vendor-Type-Code>
        <Vendor-Type-Mode>Active</Vendor-Type-Mode>
        <Vendor-Type-AC-Min>1</Vendor-Type-AC-Min>
        <Vendor-Type-AC-Max>4</Vendor-Type-AC-Max>
    </Vendor-Type>
    <Vendor-Type>
        <Vendor-Type-Id>CCCC-1</Vendor-Type-Id>
        <Vendor-Type-Code>CCCC-2</Vendor-Type-Code>
        <Vendor-Type-Mode>Active</Vendor-Type-Mode>
        <Vendor-Type-AC-Min>1</Vendor-Type-AC-Min>
        <Vendor-Type-AC-Max>4</Vendor-Type-AC-Max>
    </Vendor-Type>
    <Vendor-Type>
        <Vendor-Type-Id>DDDD-1</Vendor-Type-Id>
        <Vendor-Type-Code>DDDD-2</Vendor-Type-Code>
        <Vendor-Type-Mode>Active</Vendor-Type-Mode>
        <Vendor-Type-AC-Min>1</Vendor-Type-AC-Min>
        <Vendor-Type-AC-Max>4</Vendor-Type-AC-Max>
        <Vendor-Type-depends-on>
            <EMP-Code>DDDD-3</EMP-Code>
            <EMP-Id>DDDD-4</EMP-Id>
            <EMP-Name>DDDD-5</EMP-Name>
            <EMP-Details>
                <Property-Code>DDDD-6</Property-Code>
                <Cash-Code>DDDD-7</Cash-Code>
            </EMP-Details>
            <EMP-Details>
                <Property-Code>DDDD-8</Property-Code>
                <Cash-Code>DDDD-9</Cash-Code>
            </EMP-Details>
        </Vendor-Type-depends-on>
    </Vendor-Type>
</Vendor>
```

XSD Document:

```
 <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name="Sample">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Sample-List">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element type="xs:short" name="Id"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:short" name="Version"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Name"/>
          <xs:element name="Vendor">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Vendor-Id"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Vendor-Name"/>
                <xs:element name="Vendor-Type" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Vendor-Type-Id"/>
                      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Vendor-Type-Code"/>
                      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Vendor-Type-Mode"/>
                      <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="Vendor-Type-AC-Min"/>
                      <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="Vendor-Type-AC-Max"/>
                      <xs:element name="Vendor-Type-depends-on" minOccurs="0">
                        <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="EMP-Code"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="EMP-Id"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="EMP-Name"/>
                            <xs:element name="EMP-Details" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                              <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Property-Code"/>
                                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Cash-Code"/>
                                </xs:sequence>
                              </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                          </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                      </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

[image]

Excel Sheet Input:

```
Sample                      
Sample-List                     
Id                      
Version                     
Name                        
Vendor                      
    Vendor-Id                   
    Vendor-Name                 
    Vendor-Type                 
    Vendor-Type-Id  Vendor-Type-Code    Vendor-Type-Mode    Vendor-Type-AC-Min  Vendor-Type-AC-Max
    AAAA-1  AAAA-2  Active  1   4
    BBBB-1  BBBB-2  Active  1   4
    CCCC-1  CCCC-2  Active  1   4
    DDDD-1  DDDD-2  Active  1   4


Vendor-Type-depends-on                  
    EMP-Code    EMP-Id  EMP-Name        
    AAAA-3  AAAA-4  AAAA-5      
    NIL NIL NIL     
    NIL NIL NIL     
    DDDD-3  DDDD-4  DDDD-5      


EMP-Details Property-Code   Cash-Code           
    AAAA-6  AAAA-7          
    NIL NIL         
    NIL NIL         
    DDDD-6  DDDD-7
```

Comment: What does your Excel input look like?

Comment: Updating Excel Information: